# How can I draw a 10 unit long line?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, art

[Last question I asked like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334381/given-x-y-w-h-can-you-generate-a-rainbow-box-cuboid-with-rounded-edges) was a bit overkill so let's try something simpler instead.

How can I write an equation of the form `<stuff with x>`$=0$ that uses only $x$, such that the set of $x$ which satisfies the equation, when plotted, produces a 10 unit long line segment?

The idea of doing art with numbers interests me. Drawing a simple 1D line is part of the basics, I'd guess.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to plot the line $y=0$? What do you mean "produces" a line?

Comment: To put it simple, I wanna describe $0 <= x <= 10$ with an equation.

Comment: But you're describing the set of inequalities $0\le x$ and $x\le 10$, also written $0\le x\le 10$. I'm not sure how you could write that any more compactly.

Comment: Not more compactly, just as an equation.

Comment: $y=0$ for $x \in [0,10]$ will plot that segment.

Comment: @ElliotG The set of $x$ which satisfies the equation should produce a straight line from $x=0$ to $x=10$.

Comment: What does "produce a straight line" mean? In a graph? On a number line? You could plot a one dimensional graph using $\pi r8$'s answer and get such a line.

Comment: Then there are two answers below that seem to be what you're looking for.

Comment: @ElliotG Yes. So how's it unclear what I'm asking? They were able to answer it.

Comment: What is wrong, by the way, with the description $0 \leq x \leq 10$?

Comment: @Hurkyl It doesn't convey intent. The intent is to draw a line segment. With math.

Comment: [Plot 0 <= x <= 10](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+0+%3C%3D+x+%3C%3D+10) I'm not sure how anything else in this thread can be construed to convey intent any differently than these inequations.

Comment: @Hurkyl But that's boring. How am I supposed to turn that into art?

Comment: @SoniEx2: I don't know what you have in mind at all. How are you going to turn $x(x-10)+|x(x-10)|=0$ into art? Is it anything different than drawing a line segment?

Comment: @Hurkyl At least I can combine that with other things. How am I supposed to combine $0 <= x <= 10$ with, say, colors? How do I add color variables to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea based on parabola going through $x=0$ and $x=10$ :

$x(x-10) + |x(x-10)|=0$

Answer (score 2):

You could write $\min(x,0)^2+\min(10-x,0)^2=0$.

Answer (score 2):

$[0 \leq x \leq 10] = 1$, where $[]$ is the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).